# turning dynamic urls into static pages

Tags: php, mysql, html, dynamic, static

I have a lot of pages on my website that are the following format:

page.php?id=34587

I have read that it would be better for search engines to find pages that are dynamic, as well as creating more content for my website if I had, for example:  example.com/folder/folder/page-title-34587

How could I go about creating a lot of these pages by using php?  I've looked into having the fopen stuff to create pages, but that seems very problematic.  I've also noticed some sites are using wordpress, but does that have the functionality to create this?

Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: You have to google about url rewriting with apache

Comment: Although you've all replied with the mod_rewrite, it seems extremely complicated.  I found it very hard and not very useful.  I decided to go down the route of using a php script that could write the pages for me.  I now have created 250+ pages using this script that named the pages in a folder with

www.example.com/keyword-keyword/keyword-keyword-specific-name.php

This meant that I've created a lot of content with those that works fine.  I only needed static pages that display text and not dynamic, so the mod-rewrite really doesn't help me in this situation.  Thank you anyway though.

Comment: James, I am trying to do the same thing... how did you write your php script to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not PHP you requires, but modify your .htaccess file.
The php will be able to parse your URL to show the correct content, as it is doing that with your variable.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it would be better for search engines is that you'd have keywords in the url...so just having words instead if ids is not gonna make anything better for you. Whether you're using tags, categories or post titles to do this, make sure you're using the right words there otherwise that's not gonna help you with search engines. Check more on [mod_rewrite](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32928) though, cause thats what you're looking for